# Can't close plot using matplotlib and draw()/ion()

Tags: python, matplotlib, draw, glade

I'm trying to plot some equations using matplotlib and keep my main programa running, so I started to use draw() instead of show(). Everything is working as expected except that I cant close the plots. I click on the plot X button and does nothing. If I click on the X button on my main program, it closes ALL, as I expect it to do.

I made a simple interface with two buttons (button1 and button2, linked to its functions in the code) using Glade.

My code is following:

```
import gtk, gobject
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def gtk_main_quit(*args):
    gtk.main_quit() #fecha prog no botao fechar 

def button1(*args):
    path()

def button2(*args):
    simple()

def path(*args):    
    fig = figure()
    plt.ion()
    radius = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
    area = [3.14159, 12.56636, 28.27431, 50.26544, 78.53975, 113.09724]
    plt.plot(radius, area)
    plt.draw()

def simple(*args):    
    fig = figure()
    plt.ion()
    t = arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
    s = sin(2*pi*t)
    plot(t, s, linewidth=1.0)    
    grid(True)
    plt.draw()

App = gtk.Builder()
App.add_from_file("Thread.glade")
App.connect_signals(locals())
App.get_object('window1').show()    

gtk.main()
```

Do I have to set some closing evet to the plots?

Thx in advance

Comment: What IDE are you using to run this code?

Comment: in running from terminal. I have both Thread.glade and tread.py on same folder.

Actually I made some progress here, using draw() and ion() as well, but setting matplotlib.use('GTKAgg'). This solves my problem in most cases, except because now I cant use a spanselector I have on my main code. The plot shows, but I cant select a area.